# User defined session handling

Tags: php, session

I have my sessions stored in a database. I updated the PHP.ini file so that `session.save_handler = "user"
session.save_path = tblsession`

When I call session_start() I get an error saying "failed to initialise storage module"?

What am I missing?

Comment: And how do you declare the actual session_save_handler?

Comment: A session class is defined and the session_save_handler is called in the constructor.

Comment: You wouldn't get that error if it was done correctly / in order.

Comment: I agree mario. It works well on other pages. I can see my session data stored in the database. But when I call session_start() on this particular page, I get that error